# What is the unit size of the arguments of glviewport?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

It is unclear to me exactly what the unit size of the arguments of glviewport.

```
      glViewport(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

It appears to clearly not be in OpenGL units (the same units used when drawing). Are these numbers passed from `glviewport` automatically translated into the same unit size that corresponds with the windowing system that displays the OpenGL context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not "automatically translated" into anything. The parameters to [glViewport](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glViewport) are window coordinates. They are pixel coordinates relative to whatever the rendering surface (either the actual display or some FBO) is. (0, 0) represents the bottom-left of the rendering surface.

Comment: Ok, so they are using the coordinate system defined by the window environment that hosts the OpenGL rendering context. I assume that glViewport simply passes these numbers through to the windowing system (or context) to handle appropriately.

Comment: (0, 0) is lower left corner.

Comment: I'm more interested in the width and height arguments in my prior question.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: OpenGL is not tied to windows. You can use it to render to off-screen framebuffers as well. The arguments of glViewport address pixels in a pixel based framebuffer canvas. There's no physical unit attached to them.

Comment: ah, okay that makes sense. glViewport's units are "pixels" as opposed to the "openGL units" used in drawing.